# Javascript dates in MM/dd/yyyy format

Tags: javascript, date

I wanted to know how can I get todays date in as `July 17,2014` format. I am new to javascript..

please help

but
I have tried using `var today = new Date();`..but it gives me current date and not in the format I want.

Comment: Please do some research before posting a question. You can find this info on Google easily, and there are dozens of duplicates here on StackOverflow. Type the exact title of this question on Google, you'll see.

Comment: Sorry am new to javascript..Got the answer..Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make use of following method of Date in javascript:

```
getFullYear(); // 2011
getMonth(); // 0-11, 0-based month in year,
getDate(); // 0-31, 1-based day of month,
```